# Passing variables between piped awk statements

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have this print spooler system called PPR which, between other, control user print balance. The command "ppuser show username" print information for a given user like this.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ppuser show dpacheco
Name: dpacheco
Fullname: 
Balance: 99.00
Cutoff point: 0.00
Last Modified: Wed Oct  1 11:37:58 2014
Account lifetime: 365
Credit revoked: FALSE
```

What I need is to output a list of "*username;balance*" pair for all the system users (PPR users are the same listed in /etc/passwd).  To achieve this, I wrote this command...

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : '$user=$1 {system("ppuser show "$user)}'| awk '$1 ~ /Balance/ {print $user;$2}'
```

Explained..

1. Output the content of passwd.
2. Pipe it to an awk statement.
3. I get the username, store it in $user var and execute the "ppuser show" command with it.
4. Pipe the result to another awk statement
5. Evaluate "ppuser show" output for the line containing "Balance" and print the username and balance separated by a semicolon.

The problem..
I get an output like this

```
Balance: 100.00;100.00
Balance: -40.00;-40.00
Balance: 100.00;100.00
Balance: 100.00;100.00
Balance: 100.00;100.00
Balance: 100.00;100.00
.
.
.
```

What I see, is that the $user variable is not correctly passed between pipes.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Only what you output is passed down the pipeline. The variables are per-process. So grab both the `Balance` and `Name` lines and print them out the way you want in the second awk script. Or do it all in one awk script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of solutions.

The first one doesn't use awk at all. We extract the usernames from `/etc/passwd` using `cut`, and then `grep` the Balance: line from `ppuser`, using the Gnu grep `--label` option to output the username:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | while read -r user; do
  grep -H --label="$user" ^Balance: < <(ppuser show "$user")
done
```

If you don't have Gnu grep, you can use `printf` to print the username and extracted line in any convenient format:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | while read -r user; do
  printf "%s: %s\n" "$user" "$(ppuser show "$user" | grep ^Balance:)"
done
```

If you want to, you could drive this whole thing with `awk` instead of the shell, although it's a bit more work (and not very well tested, although in light of @EdMorton's comment I did fix some typos and verify that it works on at least one test case).

```
awk -F: '{cmd="ppuser show \""$1"\"";
          balance="";
          while ( (cmd | getline balance) > 0) {
            if (balance ~ /^Balance:/) {
              printf "%s:%s\n", $1, substr(balance, index(balance, ":") + 1);
              break;
            }
          }
          close(cmd);
         }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: That awk script will produce all sorts of weird and wonderful errors depending on the contents of the shell's `$1` and the result of calling `getline`. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to pass the value of shell variables to awk scripts and see http://awk.info/?tip/getline for how/when to use getline. You also don't need all those trailing semi-colons.

Comment: @edmorton, oops. I wasn't intending to pass $1 from the shell; just to quote it in the command line. Will edit.

Comment: @edmorton: I changed my usage of getline to more correctly respond to errors, and the bracket nesting so that close happens at the right place. So, yeah, I should have tested it. But my usage of getline corresponds precisely to example (a) in your linked page of appropriate uses.

Comment: the first method output `Balance: 100.00`, the second one `alexcaro: Balance: 100.00`.  I think I'll workout the second couse it's closer to what I want, just need to get rid of the "Balance" part.  Thanks @rici

Comment: @DagoPacheco: you could pipe through `cut -f2 -d:` or `sed 's/Balance: //'` (whichever you prefer). Or you could use the awk solution which I modified to print only the part of `balance` after the `:`.

Comment: piping awk output to sed is like hiring an electrician to wire your house and then paying someone else to attach the wires to the fuse box. awk can do anything useful that sed can do so just finish the job with awk instead of adding a pipe and some other tool at the end.

Comment: @edmorton, that is a good analogy.but if you read my reply in context, you'd see that I suggested piping grep through cut or sed, and also showed a way to accomplish it with just awk. So including the unwarranted comment about getline, that makes two unsubstantiated snarks in this thread. Have I done something to offend you?

Comment: @rici my getline comment wasn't unwarranted - you corrected your code in response to it. My other comment wasn't to you it was to the OP who said she'd solved her problem by adding a pipe to sed when her existing code was awk (except for a UUOC).

Comment: @edmorton: OP said they adopted my second solution (with no awk) and fixed the output by using a pipe through sed. (quote: I think I'll workout the second couse it's closer to what I want, just need to get rid of the "Balance" part.).

Comment: By the way .... I'm a HE ... not a SHE .... as I said, @rici 's code did the trick.  Thanks